# LabelBinarizer Not Working For 2 Categorical Values

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

The code I have used is presented below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
logging.info('performing binary encoding')

other_CSV = pd.read_csv('/home/bluedata/decisionengine/cc1.txt', sep  = '|', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
other_CSV_0 = other_CSV.copy(deep="True")
print other_CSV_0

lb_style = LabelBinarizer()

rating_text = lb_style.fit_transform(other_CSV["rating_text"])
rating_text_df = pd.DataFrame(rating_text, columns=lb_style.classes_)
other_CSV_1 = other_CSV.join(rating_text_df)

print other_CSV_1

user_foodie_level = lb_style.fit_transform(other_CSV["user_foodie_level"])
user_foodie_level_df = pd.DataFrame(user_foodie_level, columns=lb_style.classes_)
other_CSV_2 = other_CSV_1.join(user_foodie_level_df)

print other_CSV_2

lb_style = LabelBinarizer()
class_name = lb_style.fit_transform(other_CSV["class_name"])
class_name_df = pd.DataFrame(class_name, columns=lb_style.classes_)
other_CSV_3 = other_CSV_2.join(class_name_df)    
other_CSV_3.to_csv("/home/bluedata/decisionengine/ec1.txt",sep = "|", index=False, encoding = 'utf-8')
```

The column `user_foodie_level` is binary and thus contains two values: `foodie` and `big foodie`.

Using the code above to binarize this column gives me an error:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 5), indices imply (2, 5).

If I have more than 2 categorical values for the column `user_foodie_level` it gives me the desired output. I am not able to understand why it is not working if I have only two categorical values in the column.

[Data that I have used for this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIMTb.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you make your example reproducible by adding a sample of the data you're processing.

Comment: Added a snapshot of data

Comment: @MedAli Any Solution?

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, it works as intended.

The error occurs when you try to instantiate `DataFrame` with the binarized `user_foodie_level` and classes obtained with `lb_style.classes`. To solve the issue you should label **the only column** of `user_foodie_level_df`. The preferred approach is presented below:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarize
import pandas as pd

col1 = ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
col2 = ['the worst' ,'bad', 'okay', 'good', 'the best']
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[col1, col2])

print(data)

>>>            0    1     2     3         4
    0        yes   no   yes   yes       yes
    1  the worst  bad  okay  good  the best

lb = LabelBinarizer()

col1_lb = pd.DataFrame(lb.fit_transform(col1), columns=['example'])
col2_lb = lb.fit_transform(col2)
col2_tags = lb.classes_
col2_lb = pd.DataFrame(data=col2_lb, columns=col2_tags)

print(col1_lb)

>>>    user_foodie_level
    0                  1
    1                  0
    2                  1
    3                  1
    4                  1

print(col2_lb)

>>>    bad  good  okay  the best  the worst
    0    0     0     0         0          1
    1    1     0     0         0          0
    2    0     0     1         0          0
    3    0     1     0         0          0
    4    0     0     0         1          0

data = col2_lb.join(col1_lb)

print(data)

>>>    bad  good  okay  the best  the worst  example
    0    0     0     0         0          1        1
    1    1     0     0         0          0        0
    2    0     0     1         0          0        1
    3    0     1     0         0          0        1
    4    0     0     0         1          0        1
```

---

We can reproduce the same error by doing:

```
col1_lb = lb.fit_transform(col1)
col1_tags = lb.classes_

df = pd.DataFrame(col1_lb, columns=col1_tags)
```

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 5), indices imply (2, 5)

Which means that you pass two column names for a single existing column of data.

Hope that helps.

---

#### A little deeper

If there are two values like ['yes', 'no'], then the binarization creates a single column:

```
>>> [[1], 
     [0]]
```

Which means you may apply only one name to this column.

If there are three values like ['yes', 'no', 'dont know'], then the binarization creates a matrix like so:

```
>>> [[1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1]]
```

Which is exactly three columns. Thus, three names is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the Solution but i don't understand why does it work if I have three different values for the column for suppose I have foodie, big foodie and super foodie it works fine then

Comment: As I have posted, you try to apply two column names for a single column of data. When you have three different values, `LabelBinarizer()` will instantiate three columns of values. Thus, three column names will work just fine.

Comment: Check __A little deeper__ section of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the information, the sckit learn documentation does not speak anything about this which is annoying

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in the following line:

```
user_foodie_level_df = pd.DataFrame(user_foodie_level, columns=lb_style.classes_)
```

The problem is that the dimension of `user_foodie_level` is `(1,5)` and you are telling pandas that the dimension is `(2,5)` by giving the two column names `['Big Foodie' 'Foodie']` to the dataframe constructor. You need to change to something like:

```
user_foodie_level_df = pd.DataFrame(user_foodie_level, columns=['binarized_user_foodie_level'])
```

To understand why is that, check the following.

### Explanation

Label binarization of a two values (binary) categorial variable is a special case where the `LabelBinarizer()` returns a 1 dimensional vector column-wise, unlike when you have a categorical variable with more than two variables. In the latter case, the dimension column-wise is equivalent to the number of elements in `lb_style.classes_` which means that the way by which you construct your dataframe is only correct when you have more than 2 values in the categorical variable you are trying to binarize.

The following code snippet helps you see the difference in the LabelBinarizer output between the two cases:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from StringIO import StringIO


data = """
user_foodie_level
Big Foodie
Foodie
Foodie
Foodie
Big Foodie
Foodie
"""


data1 = """
user_foodie_level
Big Foodie
Foodie
Foodie
Foodie
Big Foodie
Foodie
New Foodie
"""


def test_binarization(data):

    data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
    print(data.head())

    lb_style = LabelBinarizer() 
    user_foodie_level = lb_style.fit_transform(data["user_foodie_level"]) 
    print(user_foodie_level)

    print("lb.classes_")
    print(lb_style.classes_)


print("two values categorical variable test")
test_binarization(data)

print("Three values categorical variable test")
test_binarization(data1)
```

The output of the code snippet:

```
two values categorical variable test
  user_foodie_level
0        Big Foodie
1            Foodie
2            Foodie
3            Foodie
4        Big Foodie
[[0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]
 [1]]
lb.classes_
['Big Foodie' 'Foodie']

Three values categorical variable test
  user_foodie_level
0        Big Foodie
1            Foodie
2            Foodie
3            Foodie
4        Big Foodie
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]]
lb.classes_
['Big Foodie' 'Foodie' 'New Foodie']
```